# Texture did not imported along with mesh object

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I have modeled a simple mesh object in Blender and textured it correctly in that tool by following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PGn3azej7eY). But when I try to import the blend file, only the mesh object imported and appeared in white color, without any textures assign to it.

Comment: You should convert it to fbx for import.

Answer (score 0):

create a **material** for your object and assign the **textures** that you made in blender for your object to your material in unity.

1. load the texture
2. assign the texture to material

[image]
[image]

Comment: How can I export texture made from blender?

Answer (score 0):

1. I am usually exporting fbx files from Blender. I don't remember the exact reason but it should be better than using blender files (or so I've read). With that you are also exporting UV layout but not the texture its-self.
2. When you import the fbx Unity will create a default material for you in a subfolder. Then just copy your texture (probably an image file you have somewhere on your disk) into Unity and assign the texture to the created material.

[image: Assigning texture to material]